# Django manage stream response from StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: django, video-streaming

I met a problem when create stream video from Django server.

```
generator_list = []
@gzip.gzip_page
def get_stream_video(request, stream_link):
     
   if len(generator_list) == 2:
        generator_list[1].close()
        del(generator_list[1])
    try:
        generator = detect_stream(stream_link)
        generator_list.append(generator)
        stream = StreamingHttpResponse(generator, content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
        return stream
    except:
        pass
```

Everytime I call this controller from client, it will create new instance of connection. Then I found that if those streaming response not closed, CPU will load more and more. I try to save stream generator and close but it did not work.